# Bypass Login and show dashboard for login after Registration

Tags: angular, typescript

Bypass Login and show dashboard for login after Registration : When any user Registers as a student then gets a otp verification, If otp verification is sucessfull then directly use the same username and password what he used to register and redirect it to login/dashboard.

```
    <div class="col-lg-3"><button nbButton outline status="primary" (click)="verify(3000,'bottom-end')" >Verify</button></div>
```

```
    @Input() email:string;
    @Input()  password:string;
    @Input()  userCountryCode:string;
    @Input()    userContactNo :string;
    @Input()    user_id :string;

    verify(duration,position){
            var register_data={
             email:this.email,
             password:this.password,
                        otp:this.otp,
                        type:'register'
            }
    
            if(this.otp != undefined){
    
                this.api.Otpvalue(register_data)
                .subscribe(
                  (data: any) => {
        
                    if(data['status'] == 200){
    
                      this.alert=data['status'];
                      console.log("Check Data",this.email, "password", this.password);
                      
                        this.toastrService.show(
                            `Otp Verified Successfully ! `, "Message"
                        );
                        // if (this.email==data[this.email){}
                        this.router.navigate(['pages/dashboard'])
                        this.ref.close();
                                this.alertflag=1;        
                      }
                      else if(data['status'] == 400){
                        this.alert=data['status'] ;
                      } 
                  });
                }
        }
```

Comment: just call your login method after successful registration